# Deployment won't work with Sencha SDK Tools

Tags: deployment, extjs

As nobody seems to find a solution to my problem on [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?191339-About-Sencha-SDK-Tools&p=771902), I ask my question here...

I correctly install Sencha SDk to C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta

I entered the following command:

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3
```

The first time I got:

```
Error: Can not find ..\command\sencha.js
```

I tried it again and now I don't have any message but nothing happens, the jsb3 file is not created...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out whole Sencha installation as well and it would seem that the beta tools don't work to well with Windows.
You need to deploy to C:\Program Files and **NOT** C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Beta

I noticed that when I installed it to the default folder I got the options such as *create* and I also got the error you had at one point which suggests that the paths are not correct when it installs.
When you install it to the correct path (not the path in the instructions) you get a different set of options. Create is no longer there, but generate is.